# Какая команда создает базу данных в django 1.11.1

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Какая команда создает базу данных в django 1.11.1?
"python manage.py sqlall books"  выдает сообщение "Unknown command 'sqlall'"
"python manage.py syncdb" также дает сообщение "Unknown command 'syncdb'"

Comment: makemigrations и migrate, в документации всё написано

Answer (score 1):

syncdb и sqlall достаточно давно не используются, примерно в тоже время как south был включен в ядро и миграции стали обычным делом.

Для изучения по тем учебникам что используете, лучше установить более старую версию django.

После того как создали проект, нужно применить миграции

```
makemigrations
```

Применили миграции

```
migrate
```

Эти две команды аналог старого syncdb, но гораздо более гибкий.

[Официальная документация для 11 версии](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/)

Вместо sqlall теперь используется sqlmigrate, но кроме названия приложения так же указывается название файла миграции, посмотреть все миграции showmigrations, пример

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001_initial
```

На практике, при разработке небольших сайтов удобнее использовать debug_toolbar, для просмотра sql кода. Миграции и sql код нужен обычно для ручных миграций, что требуется не так часто и в основном для старых проектов.